# How to capture selected values from a dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I created a FontDialog.cs Windows Form where my users can choose colors among other things for the text. I need to capture what the user has selected on the dialog:

[image]

Here's how I'm calling the dialog:

```
DialogsTestingGrounds.FontDialog dialog = new FontDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

How can I capture the selected values, I imagine I have to create properties for everything I want to transfer on the FontDialog.cs form end, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary, you can use, ie, dialog.Font to get the selected font,
dialog.Color for the color and so on...

Answer (score 3):

What you would want to do is expose properties on your FontDialog that make the values available.  You could then use dialog.PropertyName to reference it by the name of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Mitchel's answer will work but you might want to incorporate a couple other items along the same line.

- Have a public property (per Mitchel's
  answer).
- Have a public constructor on your
  form with the type of the property as
  an argument so you can pass in the value
  in question (this would allow you have the dialog prepopulated with old selection).
- Surround your call to your dialog
  with a check for dialogresult so you
  only change the value when the user
  wants to. (note the process for this is different in WPF)
- Felice is also right in that you
  don't really need to create a new
  font dialog if the only thing you
  care about is the font. There is a
  built in font dialog in .Net
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

So the internals of your dialog class may look like this psuedo code.

```
    public Font SelectedFont { get; set; }
    public FontDialog()
    {
       //set your defaults here
    }

    public FontDialog (Font font)
    {
       SelectedFont = font;
       //dont forget to set the passed in font to your ui values here
    }

    private void acceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedFont = //How ever you create your font object;
    }
```

Then to call your function (assumes the the acceptButton above is the forms AcceptButton)

```
DialogsTestingGrounds.FontDialog dialog = new FontDialog();
if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     //Do Something
```

Comment: In your constructor, "SelectedFont = font" instead of "Font = font"; btw "Font=font" compiles, because the form inherits a Font property from its parent class Control.

Comment: And providing default values through overloaded constructors is superfluous. Sergio could pass default values through the properties as well but "before" he shows the dialog (as we do when initializing a Filter on a OpenFileDialog for instance)